# Why does Q object return duplicated results?

Tags: python, django

I have a `ViewSet` that has a `get_queryset` method. This method filters objects using a `Q` object:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    request = self.request
    query = Ticket.objects.filter(
                            Q(message_type__users__in=[request.user])|
                            Q(reference__to_user=request.user)
                            )
    return query
```

output:

```
[<Ticket: 24>, <Ticket: 24>, <Ticket: 24>, <Ticket: 24>]
```

it returns the same Ticket (id = 24) four times. For 'GET' requests from client, i get `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception:

```
get() returned more than one Ticket -- it returned 4!
```

Why does Q object return multiple results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the way SQL works, it means you have 1 ticket, but either 4 `message_type` or 4 `reference` objects related to that ticket, so when you `JOIN`, all of them will be returned.

Using `.distinct()` should solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

This filters down to SQL: The way a query is built can result in the same row either satisfying more than one condition or satisfying the same condition more than once.

If this is the best way to format your query, try tacking on `.distinct()` to avoid duplicate results.